# Where do the promise callback arguments come from

Tags: javascript

I study promises. Typical promise would look like this:

```js
let cleanMyRoomPromiseCallback = function(resolve, reject) {//where "resolve" and "reject" come from?
 resolve("My room is clear!"); 
}

let cleanMyRoom = new Promise(cleanMyRoomPromiseCallback)
.then((onCleanMyRoomResolve)=> {
 console.log(onCleanMyRoomResolve);
})
```

The function `cleanMyRoomPromiseCallback` has two parameters: `resolve` and `reject`. When that function is passed to the constructor of `Promise` they are not defined seems to me. These identifiers are just some text. How are they evaluated? Do they come/evaluate from the `Promise` constructor itself?

Comment: Yes exactly. The `Promise` constructor calls the passed callback and passes the resolve and reject function. What these functions actually do is up to the browser implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The promise constructor behaves like this:

```
 function Promise(callback){
   const handlers = [];

   function resolve(value){
     for(const [success] of handlers)
        if(success) success(value);
   }

  function reject(error){
     for(const [, catch] of handlers)
        if(catch) catch(error);
  }

  // Now call the callback and pass the functions:
  callback(resolve, reject);

  // Return the created promise...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `Promise` constructor takes a function as an argument, which also requires 2 functions as parameters (the `resolve` and `reject` functions you see there). If you want to read more about the Promise constructor, the MDN article is a good way to get up to speed:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer the broader question of "where do callback arguments come from?"

The short-and-sweet answer is that the arguments are passed by whatever calls the callback.

A simple example should make this clear.

If we define a function that takes a callback:

```
function example(callback) {...}
```

The callback needs to be called somewhere within the function to be useful:

```
function example(callback) {
  callback('Hello World!')
}
```

When you want to use the function, you need to know what parameters will be passed to the callback. In our example, there's only one argument, so the callback should handle that argument:

```
example(function (text) {
  console.log(text) // writes "Hello World!" to the console
})
```

---

When you use `new Promise`, the constructor passes two arguments that are functions when it calls its callback.